# CosmosDB - Query with a WHERE condition on second level JSON property?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Our CosmosDB JSON data is structured like so:

```
    "Fields": [
        {
            "FieldId": 32833,
            "FieldValue": "Others",
            "ParentFieldName": null,
            "FieldName": "<p>Plastic_type</p>32833"
        },
    ]
```

How would I write a WHERE clause if I wanted to get all records with a `Fields.FieldValue = 'Others'`? I tried the query below but it is not getting me any results:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["Fields"]["FieldValue"] LIKE '%Others%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
SELECT r.id, r.Fields FROM r
JOIN f in r. Fields
WHERE f.FieldValue = 'Others'
```

You may find this link helpful in understanding how to query arrays in Cosmos DB: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I did try the following code but it's not following the condition - values without the 'Others' keyword are still appearing: `SELECT c.id, c.Fields FROM c
JOIN e IN c.Fields WHERE e.FieldValue LIKE '%Others%'` Do you know where I went wrong with the WHERE clause? https://imgur.com/tezuIKz

Comment: Please edit your question and include some sample documents. Thanks.

Comment: I found the cause, the `c.Fields` should have used the identifier `e` instead of `c`. Like so: `SELECT c.WebTrfId, e FROM c JOIN e IN c.Fields WHERE e.FieldValue LIKE '%Others%'`

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```sql
SELECT c.id,
ARRAY(SELECT  distinct  value d FROM c join d IN c.Fields WHERE d.FieldValue LIKE  '%Others%') 
as field FROM c
```

In this code, the subquery returns an array of objects where the `FieldValue` property contains the string `'Others'`. Then ARRAY() is applied to the result of the subquery to aggregate the results of the subquery into an array. I have taken sample input documents and below is the input and output data.

**Input:**
`Select * from c`

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldId": 32833,
                "FieldValue": "Others - As",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Plastic_type</p>32833"
            },
            {
                "FieldId": 32834,
                "FieldValue": "After Wash",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Wash</p>32834"
            },
            {
                "FieldId": 32835,
                "FieldValue": "Others - Bs",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Wash</p>32835"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldId": 32836,
                "FieldValue": "Others - GH",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Good</p>32836"
            },
            {
                "FieldId": 32837,
                "FieldValue": "After Wash",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Wash</p>32837"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "field": [
            {
                "FieldId": 32833,
                "FieldValue": "Others - As",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Plastic_type</p>32833"
            },
            {
                "FieldId": 32835,
                "FieldValue": "Others - Bs",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Wash</p>32835"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "field": [
            {
                "FieldId": 32836,
                "FieldValue": "Others - GH",
                "ParentFieldName": null,
                "FieldName": "<p>Good</p>32836"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```